# Style is not loading in the child theme

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

I am new in the magento 2 and created child theme first time , you can see here http://www.neplyn.in/staging/

Css is not loading not sure why.

DO I need to copy the parent theme css and put in child theme folder?

Comment: Have you configure your child theme from backend https://prnt.sc/13djxnr

Comment: Yes, Is there any other option to do that ?

Comment: can you please describe me in detail msg on skye me live:.cid.2ade8fa706eb8d27